# Titanium: How do I get the data from this function?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I had everything working when I had all this code within app.js, but I'm having a fit since I moved functions and windows into their own separate files.

In main_Window.js I set an event listener on the main window when it opens to run a function and return table data.  I know the function is getting the data because I can print it out in the console, but it's not passing it back into my event listener.

*snippet of loadFeed.js*:

```
//gets data and builds table rows
//I can see this in the console
Ti.API.info('tableData: ' + JSON.stringify(rowData));

//but it's not getting returned to my variable 
//in main_Window.js
return rowData;
```

*snippet of main_Window.js*

```
var newsFeed = require('loadFeed');

win.addEventListener("open",function(){
var tableData = newsFeed.loadFeed();

//now the console says that tableData is undefined  
Ti.API.info('tableData: ' + JSON.stringify(tableData));

tableView.setData(tableData);
});
```

*app.js*

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var be_url = 'http://192.168.1.200:10080';

//later we will get these values from user input
var usr_email =  'user1@wordout.tv';
var usr_password = 'fake_password';

//set from authenticate.js
var usr_session;

//create the main window below
var mainWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Main Window',
    width: Ti.UI.Fill,
    height: Ti.UI.Fill,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    navBarHidden: 'true',
    url: 'ui/common/main_Window.js'
});

//validating email and password.  
//Storing userid in session and returning sessionid for future data calls.
//opens mainWin when successfully authenticated
var authorize = require('ui/common/authenticate');
authorize();
```

Comment: can you check typeOf newsFeed ? in  main_Window.js?

Comment: `[ERROR] :  OpenGLRenderer:   GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

`[INFO] :   tableData: undefined`

`[INFO] :   typeof: undefined`
`[ERROR] :  TableViewProxy: Invalid value, expected type Array.`

`[INFO] :   JSON Data: [{"type":"s"....some more data`

`[INFO] :   Header Code: 200`

`[INFO] :   Header Location: http://192.168.1.200:10080`

`[INFO] :   tableData: [{"enabled":true,"backgroundRepeat":false,....some more data`

Comment: When I do this in main_Window.js:  `var tableData = [];` `tableData.push(newsFeed.loadFeed());`
I get this in the console:  `[INFO] :   tableData: [null]` `[INFO] :   typeof: object`

Comment: is the loadFeed.js present on the same level as main_Window.js?

Comment: They are both in the same folder if that's what you are asking?  I am including loadFeed.js inside of main_Window.js (as you can see).

Comment: As far as i can see, you have called a web service in loadFeed.js and are trying to send the data to the main_Window.js using just a return ?

Comment: Exactly.  I had this working when I had all the window code inside app.js.  (loadFeed.js was still a module that I included inside app.js.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57068/discussion-between-dragon-and-tdave00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do the following :

modify your loadFeed function to accept a callback and inside the callback  do :

```
tableView.setData(tableData);
```

You are facing a very common Issue, The ajax request you (would) have used is an asynchronous request.
So the control does not wait till you receive the values from the server.Instead it does the return statement first.For using commonjs method you have to add a callback inside your module to update the values when you receive data from server.

check the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)

you have to call your callback inside onload function.

Comment: Reading up on callbacks.  My terminology is not so great.

Comment: send a function as a Parameter inside newsFeed.loadFeed() and inside that function write code to update.

Comment: Do I create the callback function in main_Window.js?

Comment: Thanks @Dragon.  I learned something very helpful!  Been banging my head against this for 2 days.

Comment: Yes and send it like : var tableData = newsFeed.loadFeed(YOUR_FUNCTION);